# Event Binding in The Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, compiler-errors

I am facing certain error with $event in angular 11. Please someone help me to debug it..
$event error in angular
**Error message :**
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hscNn.png)

```html
Error: src/app/recipes/recipes.component.html:4:26 - error TS2739: Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'Recipe': name, description, imagePath

4     (recipeWasSelected)="selectedRecipe=$event"></app-recipe-list>
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/recipes/recipes.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './recipes.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component RecipesComponent.


Error: src/app/shopping-list/shopping-list.component.html:3:64 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Ingridient'.
  Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'Ingridient': name, amount

3         <app-shopping-edit (ingridientAdded)=onIngridientAdded($event)></app-shopping-edit>
                                                                 ~~~~~~

  src/app/shopping-list/shopping-list.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './shopping-list.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ShoppingListComponent.
```

***CODE LINK:***

> https://github.com/Umang01-hash/RecipeBook

Answer (score 1):

> Error: src/app/recipes/recipes.component.html:4:26

That is a typo, you listen to `recipeWasSelected` while your output is named `recpieWasSelected` within `RecipesListComponent`

> Error: src/app/shopping-list/shopping-list.component.html:3:64

Basically the same, but I wouldn't call that "typo" in that case. You listen to `ingridientAdded`, while your output is named `ingridientEmitter` within `ShoppingEditComponent`.

**Extended answer as per your comment**

You have 2 further issues.

- The `click` event within `recipes-item.component.html` is not a function call, please add `()`
- The EventEmitter name `recipeWasSelected` within `RecipesListComponent` is also wrong

After all I recommend to take hand on a good IDE, it would highlight you most of those issues

Comment: Thankyou so much MoxxiManagarm for the help. Correcting my mistake i am able to compile the code succesfully but the app is not working correctly i.e wheni click on the recipe it's details are not shown and add ingridiemt also redirects to home page can you please help me solve that

Answer (score 0):

the mistake is here:

```
<app-shopping-edit (ingridientAdded)="onIngridientAdded($event)"> </app-shopping-edit>
```

The name of the Output parameter in the tag is incorrect.

You have to change the word `(ingridientAdded)` to `(ingridientEmitter)`

a working application at work

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-48vyda?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thankyou so much Onur Özkır for the help. Correcting my mistake i am able to compile the code succesfully but the app is not working correctly i.e wheni click on the recipe it's details are not shown and add ingridiemt also redirects to home page can you please help me solve that